# Getting RID of thickbox!

Tags: functions, thickbox

I want to get rid of the complete thickbox css js and loading gif. Can anybody give me the correct way to get rid of it all via functions.php ?

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing front end only, right?

```
function wpse71503_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_style('thickbox');
        wp_deregister_script('thickbox');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'wpse71503_init');
```

Comment: That did it! Nice!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the plugin yourself?
Then deactivate and/or delete it from the Plugin section of your WordPress Dashboard.

Comment: No, it's the WP built in thickbox, not a plugin. There must be a way to deregister or disable it via functions.php.